# Already existing List assignment to new variable confuses computations in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wrote the following code in Rcpp

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>


// [[Rcpp::export]]

List Dee(int K, List n_1, List n_2, int k){

List n(K);
n = n_1;
n[k] = as<arma::mat>(n_2[k]);

return n_1;
}
```

Where I have two lists as inputs `n_1` and `n_2`. Inside the function `Dee` I create a new List `n` where I assign as `n=n_1`. The problem now is that whatever change I make to the List `n` it is also happening to List `n_1`. To observe that I implemented the following example.

```
K = 2

n_1 = list()
n_1[[1]] = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),K+1,K+1)
n_1[[2]] = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),K+1,K+1)

n_2 = list()
n_2[[1]] = matrix(c(-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9),K+1,K+1)
n_2[[2]] = matrix(c(-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9),K+1,K+1)
```

The result when I run the function `Dee` is

```
k = 0 #just want to change the first matrix of list n
Dee(K,n_1,n_2,k)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1    4   -7
[2,]    2   -5    8
[3,]   -3    6   -9

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

where the correct result should have been

```
 n_1
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

because inside the function `Dee` I never assigned or made a changed to list `n_1`. I only changed the `k` element of List `n`.

I assume that in the function `Dee` I have to find an optimal way of making this assignment `n = n_1`.

Comment: Use clone to force a deep copy?

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much Ronald!! So, I searched now that C++ is a copy by reference system, so it is necessary to use ```clone``` when creating copies, interesting.